# How to return ALL HTML from a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to get all of the source code from a webpage.
So if I have a webpage like this:
`<head>
  head
</head>
<body>
  body
</body>`

How would I make a JS program I could run from the console that would return the entire HTML source code? If I were to run it on a webpage's console, it would output it's source.

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched somewhere before asking here?

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the DTD and the full HTML (the markup) of a page, you can do this:

```js
let dO = document.doctype;
let dtd = '';
if (dO) {
    dtd = `<!DOCTYPE ${dO.name}${dO.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + dO.publicId + '"' : ''}${dO.systemId ? ' "' + dO.systemId + '"': ''}`.trim() + '>\n';
}
let htmlOfPage = dtd + document.documentElement.outerHTML;

console.log(htmlOfPage);
```

The contents of the linked resources (e.g. stylesheets and scripts) are not included. Note, that if you're going to run this in the console, change `let`s to `var`s to avoid a redefinition error when run more than once on a page.

Comment: This is what the actual source code looks like:<!DOCTYPE html>


    <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive">

    <head>

        <title>javascript - How to return ALL HTML from a webpage? - Stack Overflow</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.....

Comment: Yep, the stack snippet shows its own markup, which is different from yours. I'll put the DTD also to the answer later, it's a bit late here = ). Notice also, that the output is not exactly the _source code_, which is the original code from the server. Rather it is the current markup, it includes also any changes made by scripts after loading the page.

Answer (score 4):

This will return the entire HTMLDocument:

```
<script>
   console.log(window.document)
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: `var doc = window.document;
  console.log(doc.title); // Hello, World!`

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, reading the title, it says they want to get the HTML of the entre page, not a DOM tree ..?

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: hmm... for me, it just says [object HTMLDocument]. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Odog8 That maybe browser-dependent, try `console.dir(...)`.

Comment: @Teemu it kind of worked. It still passed quite a few important things. the New Tab page for Chrome ends up looking a little screwy...

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

This will return all code from a webpage.